# About selling old LEGO, by the pound or assembled?

Tags: shopping

I was just wondering how much does a pound of bulk usually sell for. I also have tons of star wars mini-figs, including tons of clone troopers of different kinds, stormtroopers, battle droids, but some are relatively worn, are they worth anything? I also have some pretty destroyed sets that can probably be rebuilt but I don't have the instructions anymore, should I just disassemble them?

Comment: I think the good answer better cover how to actually sell effectively, is bricklink good for selling small amounts.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a pound of LEGO goes $5-$10, depending on what's included and the condition of the parts.

As far as how much your minifigures are worth, you can go to BrickLink.com, find the minifigures you have in their database, and check the Price Guide. It will list all the currently available minifigs sold by shops around the world, and sales figures from the past six month. There are separate columns for new and used figures, so you will get a good idea of what minifigs in similar condition as yours are selling for. To get you started, here is the main page for all the Star Wars figures: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=M&catString=65&itemBrand=1000

In regards to sets, you can check the BrickLink Price Guide for those as well. Some might be worth selling assembled, while for others it doesn't matter. You can download instruction from LEGO's website here:  https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions

Comment: I'm also interested. Is it easy to sell via bricklink? (maybe it deserves a separate question...). I'm at all not sure ordinary lego user can sell easily at these prices..

Comment: Alexei, maybe you can clarify what is your definition of easy. In general, yes, selling on BL is easy. You follow the directions to set up an account and open a store. You select the parts/sets/minifigs you have, their condition, how many you have, etc., then add them to your store inventory. You wait for orders, follow the directions to send out invoices, collect payment, and ship packages. If you ever sold on anything eBay it is basically the same process. If not, it will probably take you a bit longer. People from all walks of life and all countries sell on both on eBay and BrickLink.